# org.apache.felix.shell.Command and Servicemix

Tags: apache-karaf, apache-felix, apache-servicemix, gogo-shell

I have implemented a set of "org.apache.felix.shell.Command"s with the purpose of utilizing it in Apache Servicemix. The commands are being registered with "org.osgi.framework.BundleActivator" (Blueprint not involved as it often collides with Spring that I use extensively). I have tested the commands with Pax-Exam and all seems to be working fine. However when deployed to the actual Servicemix container the commands are not available.

I have stumbled upon the following (http://t20025.apache-karaf-user.apachetalks.us/getting-felix-scr-commands-to-show-up-in-karaf-t20025.html), however the suggested solution is not working for me.

Did anyone experienced similar problem and managed to find a working solution?

Comment: We got a bunch of Camel commands for Karaf, maybe peak at our code, to see if you can find anything that helps - https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/master/platforms/karaf/commands

Comment: It might help if you can somehow describe or publish a small project containing a command that did not work.